# How would you refactor this HAML code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, haml

I have this haml snippet representing a like/dislike button

```
- if @post.liked_by?(current_user)
  = button_to post_likes_path(@post), method: :delete, class: 'post-like-btn' do
    %i.fa.fa-heart.color-red
    = @post.likes
    .footer-caption= pluralize(@post.likes, 'like', 'likes')
- else
  = button_to post_likes_path(@post), method: :post, class: 'post-like-btn' do
    %i.fa.fa-heart
    = @post.likes
    .footer-caption= pluralize(@post.likes, 'like', 'likes')
```

But I really feel like it could DRYed up. My first try:

```
= button_to post_likes_path(@post), method: (@post.liked_by?(current_user) ? :delete : :post), class: 'post-like-btn' do
  %i{class: "fa fa-heart#{@post.liked_by?(current_user) ? ' color-red' : ''}"}
  = @post.likes
  .footer-caption= pluralize(@post.likes, 'like', 'likes')
```

But I find that awful, expecially for the FontAwesome icon... Any idea?

Comment: Questions asking to improve and critique functioning code are more suitable at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- method = @post.liked_by?(current_user) ? :delete : :post
- class  = @post.liked_by?(current_user) ? ".color-red" : ""

= button_to post_likes_path(@post), method: #{method}, class: 'post-like-btn' do
    %i.fa.fa-heart#{class}
       = @post.likes
       .footer-caption= pluralize(@post.likes, 'like')
```

I'm sure there's a better way, but with the code you've presented, that's what I'd do. I think you can refactor further, but it would require using the controller & merging the classes to be less specific (I.E using container `div`s)

Comment: You mean like a ".liked" and ".not-liked" classes around the button_to?

Comment: Yep like that - it will give you the ability to style all the elements with the CSS, rather than doing it individually with Rails

Comment: Wouldn't that just be moving the #{class} outside the button? I would still need a condition to peek the right class. And I would still have to calculate the method for the button. Can't see how a css class would help here :(

Comment: The CSS will only affect the styling - which is partly what I can see the issue will be. If you need to change something Rails-specific, you'll simply be able to use a conditional statement (`if`) like what I've done to change that data. In terms of refactoring, it's basically just a case of DRYING up your styling as well as your structure - which are two different elements

Comment: You can’t have a variable named `class`, it’s a keyword and this code will give an error You need to use something else (`icon_color` maybe).

Comment: `%i.fa.fa-heart#{class}` will give an error, even if you change `class` to something valid. You can do something like `%i.fa.fa-heart{:class => icon_color}` though.